# Google Maps API Search Along Route

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way I can use Google Maps/Google Places API to search for places along a route like the app allows?

Answer (score 0):

hello using placeApi u can not draw route for drawing route between two place u need to use  direction Api for that u can use this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro